# Angular prints page twice

Tags: css, angular, printing

Following angular component prints the page always twice.

```
template: `
    <p-dialog [(visible)]="visible && eventId"
              [modal]="true" [style]="{width: '40vw'}" position="top"
              (onHide)="onClose()">
        <div class="print-label">
            <span>20565862</span>
        </div>
        <p-footer>
            <p-button icon="pi pi-print" styleClass="p-button-primary mr-2 mb-2"
                      label="print"
                      (onClick)="onPrint()"
            ></p-button>
            <p-button icon="pi pi-times" styleClass="p-button-outlined mr-2 mb-2"
                      label="close"
                      (onClick)="onClose()"
            ></p-button>
        </p-footer>
    </p-dialog>
`, styles: [`

    .print-label {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 100px;
        font-weight: 900;
    }

    @media print {
        .print-label {
            font-size: 60px;
            font-weight: 900;
            padding-top: 25px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: -105px;
            top: 0;
        }

        .print-label * {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    }
`]
```

This is the onPrint methode:

```
onPrint() {
    window.print();
}
```

This is what the browser print dialog shows:
[image]

I would need to print the page just once. Is there a way to force it to only print the first page?

Comment: Can you add the code of `onPrint` to the question?